# How to change UIView elements based on timing schedule in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiview, nstimer

I am developing an app in which an `UIView` has elements(like image,button etc) which are labeled with the time text like 2:30 PM,3:30 PM. Now I want that when my viewDidLoad called and if current time has passed 2:30 PM than the view of this object should changed and if current time has not passed 3:30 PM than its view should remain as it is.

[image]

As shown in the figure if the current time passed 12:30 PM and 2:15 PM than the `view` of these two button should changed and other buttons view should remain as it is.

I have tried `NSDate` and `NSDateFormatter` classes by converting the string into integer and compare it but I didn't get the perfect output.

Do I need to use `NSTimer` class here?

Comment: you need an NSTimer, you can find plenty of examples in SO...

Comment: Do you know any good tutorial on that?

Comment: please, see my answer. It's so easy that you do not need a tutorial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use NSTimer class for that.I was facing same issue and I used [NSDate compare] class.
You will have to get the titleLable text of the button and store it as NSString and than using NSDate,NSDateFormatter class compare this string and the current time.

Like this:

```
NSString *str1 = btn1.titleLabel.text;

NSDate *occDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSString *occStr = [formatter stringFromDate:occDate];
NSDate *lDate = [formatter dateFromString:occStr];
NSDate *d1 = [formatter dateFromString:str1];

NSComparisonResult result1 = [lDate compare:d1];
if(result1 == NSOrderedDescending)
{
    [btn1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSTimer` to do what you described.

Add this to your `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.uiTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                 target:self
                 selector:@selector(updateUI:)
                 userInfo:nil
                 repeats:YES];
```

This timer (don't forget to define a property to manage it) will call its target method every 5 seconds, but you can change that as per your requirements.

Then, define a target method like this, where you modify your UI:

```
- (void)updateUI:(NSTimer*)timer {

     <if time is less than X, then… else …>
}
```

Don't forget to invalidate the timer when you are done with it (e.g. in `viewDidDisappear`):

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self.uiTimer invalidate];
    self.uiTimer = nil;
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question by adding an image.How can i use NSTimer with NSDate?(current time).

Comment: you do not use the time with NSDate. what you do is, in `updateUI`, get the current time, then compare it each of your buttons (are they in an array?); if a button is "older" than current time, you change it. I cannot provide more help because I do not know what your code looks like… but I hope this will get you in the right direction. You need to associate an NSDate to each button, then compare that date to the current time.

Comment: Dealloc will never be called as timer retains it's target, is repeatable and is never invalidated, so you should invalidate it somewhere in viewDidDisappear(if it's the "leaf"), or when going back from that screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method to be called every 60 minutes:

---

.h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
```

---

.m file

```
- (void)startTimer {
    if (timer.isValid)
        return;
    timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:3600 target:self selector:@selector(myMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [timer fire];
}

- (void)myMethod {
// change element code
}
```